# Columns alignment in in h:panelGrid

Tags: css, html, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have this table with 3 columns. The third column is for validation message which by default is empty.

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid id="panel" styleClass="data_table_pricing" columns="3">

        <h:outputText value="Title"/>

        <h:inputText id="title" value="#{pricingForm.title}" validatorMessage="Value is too big.">
            <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="40" />
            <f:ajax event="change" render="@form"/>
        </h:inputText>

        <h:message id="title_message" for="title" style="color:red"/>

        <!-- // -->

        <h:outputText value="First name"/>

        <h:inputText id="first_name" value="#{pricingForm.firstName}" validatorMessage="Value is too big.">
            <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="40" />
            <f:ajax event="change" render="@form"/>
        </h:inputText>

        <h:message id="first_name_message" for="first_name" style="color:red"/>

        <!-- // -->

        <h:outputText value="Last name"/>

        <h:inputText id="last_name" value="#{pricingForm.lastName}" validatorMessage="Value is too big.">
            <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="40" />
            <f:ajax event="change" render="@form"/>
        </h:inputText>

        <h:message id="last_name_message" for="last_name" style="color:red"/>

        <!-- // -->

    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:commandLink value="reset" class="link" type="reset" style="margin: 20px;">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:commandLink value="Next" class="link" style="margin: 20px;" actionListener="#{pricingForm.calculatorPage()}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
    </h:commandLink>

</h:form>
```

I use this CSS code to style the table:

```
.data_table_pricing {
    border-spacing: 12px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I need to find a way to fix the size the columns. When validation message appears the second column is pushed to the left.

Is there any way to fix the size of the columns?

Comment: Can you setup a demo of the current code?

Comment: Sure: http://54.68.115.94:8080/Web_site/pricing_form.xhtml Open the page and insert more than 40 characters into any input field form and click on the Next button or outside of the from. You will see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a fixed width to the td element prevents the column jump.

```
.data_table_pricing tbody tr td {
  width: 33%;
}
```

**Edit:**

Solution for variable number of table columns and should be used over above method.

```
table.data_table_pricing {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Well, I also tried to implement this in a table with 4 columns - it's looking very shrink. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Hmmm. Can you say what you mean by shrink here? How do you want your output to be?

Comment: I applied you code here http://54.68.115.94:8080/Web_site/pricing_form.xhtml   and here  http://54.68.115.94:8080/Web_site/pricing_calculator.xhtml  on the second page insert some String value to see validation error message.